# ShareThis.com Social Media Buttons HitCounter Mishap

Tags: javascript, html, social-networking, sharethis

I have social media share and like buttons on my page. There is a problem with the hitcount that the Facebook buttons get. If I "Share" the page on Facebook it gets counted toward the "Likes" the next time I refresh the page.

`<span class='st_facebook_hcount' st_title='$videoTitle' displayText='Facebook'></span>
 <span class='st_twitter_hcount' st_title='$videoTitle' displayText='Tweet'></span>
 <span class='st_sharethis_hcount' st_title='$videoTitle' displayText='share'></span>
 <span class='st_fblike_hcount' st_title='$videoTitle' displayText='Facebook Like'></span>
 <span class='st_plusone_hcount' st_title='$videoTitle' displayText='Google +1'></span>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "69070f45-d198-4d82-8b1f-9715232e78e8"}); </script>
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong? I'm stuck >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong, its working as intended by Facebook

Here is what Facebook says the number is:

Taken from: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

What makes up the number shown on my Like button?

The number shown is the sum of:

The number of likes of this URL
The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.

Hope this helps..